# Apply biserial function to all columns of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, correlation

In R, I have a data frame with 100 columns. I want to apply biserial(x,y) where I need to iterate columns for x. 
Example:

```
biserial(x=train5$GENDER,y=train5$RESPONDERS)
biserial(x=train5$LEGAL_ENTITY,y=train5$RESPONDERS)
biserial(x=train5$AGE,y=train5$RESPONDERS)
```

This is what I do for First three columns, I need to replace values of x by column names of dataframe in iterative manner and I need to calculate their  biserial values.

Comment: What language is this written in, R? (That's my hunch)

Comment: R Programming Language

Comment: Or maybe this one `sapply(1:ncol(dtrain5), function(i) biserial.cor(df[,i],train5$RESPONDERS))`

Comment: Output of biserial is 1*1 matrix, how to remove its dimesnions

Comment: thabnks @Adamm , it worked